# Adding JTextFields on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I've been at this for a while and I feel like I'm almost there,

I'm trying to add TextFields to a JPanel at the click of a button, the Jpanel may or may not already have JTextFields in it.

At the moment the new JTextFields appear, but only as lines and if there are already JTextFields there they are painted over them.

I'm nearing the end of my project and really appreciate any help on this.

```
public class CDPopup extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JLabel artist, songName, songLength, songNumber;
private JTextField artistTBox;
private JButton addSong, addAlbum, update;
private DigiProduct p;
private Border space = (Border) BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10,10);
private Border line = (Border) BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
private Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(space, line);

private Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20);
private GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

private ProdDialog prodDialog;

private JTextField song9, song10, song11, song12, song13, song8, song7, song6, song5, song4, song1, song2, song3,
length9, length10, length11, length12, length13, length8, length7, length6, length5, length4, length1, length2,
length3;

JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx = { song1 = new JTextField(),
        song2 = new JTextField(), song3 = new JTextField(),
        song4 = new JTextField(), song5 = new JTextField(),
        song6 = new JTextField(), song7 = new JTextField(),
        song8 = new JTextField(), song9 = new JTextField(),
        song10 = new JTextField(), song11 = new JTextField(),
        song12 = new JTextField(), song13 = new JTextField()};

JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx2 = { length1 = new JTextField(),
        length2 = new JTextField(), length3 = new JTextField(),
        length4 = new JTextField(), length5 = new JTextField(),
        length6 = new JTextField(), length7 = new JTextField(),
        length8 = new JTextField(), length9 = new JTextField(),
        length10 = new JTextField(), length11 = new JTextField(),
        length12 = new JTextField(), length13 = new JTextField()};

private JLabel[] digiProdDetailLb;

private DigiProductList digiProductList;

private ArrayList<Song> alist = new  ArrayList<Song>();



public CDPopup(DigiProduct p, DigiProductList digiProductList, ProdDialog  prodDialog) {




    this.prodDialog = prodDialog;
    this.digiProductList = digiProductList;
    this.setName("cd");
    this.p = p;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    if(p.getAlbum().getSongList().size() >= 15)
    {
        this.setSize(690, 600);
    }
    else if(p.getAlbum().getSongList().size() < 11)
    {
        this.setSize(690, 410);
    }
    else
    {
        this.setSize(690, 490);
    }
    JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setBorder(new TitledBorder("CD"));



    addFields( p.getAlbum().getSongList().size(), false);



    JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    detailsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 80));
    this.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel details = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    details.setBorder(border);
    details.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 130));
    detailsPanel.add(details, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel spacer = new JPanel();
    spacer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    detailsPanel.add(spacer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    artist = new JLabel(" Artist");
    details.add(artist, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    artistTBox = new JTextField(10);

    details.add(artistTBox, gc);



    JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    addSong = new JButton("Add Song");
    addSong.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 30));
    addSong.addActionListener(this);
    bottom.add(addSong);

    update = new JButton("Update");
    update.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 30));
    update.addActionListener(this);
    bottom.add(update);


    addAlbum = new JButton("Add Album");
    addAlbum.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 30));
    addAlbum.addActionListener(this);
    bottom.add(addAlbum);
    this.setVisible(true);



}



public void addFields(int size, boolean newSong)
{

    JPanel songs = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    songs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 200));
    songs.setBorder(border);

    songNumber = new JLabel(" No.");
    songName = new JLabel("Song");
    songLength = new JLabel("Length");

    JLabel[] digiProdDetailLb = new JLabel[size];
    if(newSong == true)
    {
        JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx = new JTextField[size];
        JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx2 = new JTextField[size];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        int num = i +1;

        if (i == 0) {
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            songs.add(songNumber, gc);
        }

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = i + 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        gc.weightx = 2.0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        digiProdDetailLb[i] = new JLabel(" " + num);
        digiProdDetailLb[i].setFont(font);
        songs.add(digiProdDetailLb[i], gc);

        if (i == 0) {
            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            songs.add(songName, gc);
        }
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = i + 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        gc.weightx = 2.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        if(newSong == true)
        {
            digiProdDetailBx[i] = new JTextField(100);
        }
        else
        {
        digiProdDetailBx[i] = new JTextField(p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getSong_name());
        }
        digiProdDetailBx[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
        songs.add(digiProdDetailBx[i], gc);

        if (i == 0) {
            gc.gridx = 3;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            songs.add(songLength, gc);
        }
        gc.gridx = 3;
        gc.gridy = i + 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        gc.weightx = 2.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        if(newSong == true)
        {
            digiProdDetailBx2[i] = new JTextField(100);
        }
        else
        {
        digiProdDetailBx2[i] = new  JTextField(p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getSong_length());
        }
        digiProdDetailBx2[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
        songs.add(digiProdDetailBx2[i], gc);

    }
    ;

    this.add(songs, BorderLayout.EAST);


}

public void updateEmployee() {



        for(int i = 0 ; i < p.getAlbum().getSongList().size(); i++)
        {

            Song s = new        Song(p.getProd_id(),p.getAlbum().getSongList().get(i).getProd_id(), 
                    digiProdDetailBx[i].getText(),        digiProdDetailBx2[i].getText());
            alist.add(s);
        }



        CD c = new CD(alist);



        DigiProduct cd = new DigiProduct(p.getProd_id(),
                p.getProd_type(),
                p.getDigi_id(),
                p.getCd_id(),
                p.getArtist_id(),
                p.getAlbumName(),
                p.getCostPrice(),
                p.getSellPrice(),
                p.getCurrent_stock(),
                p.getAge_rating(),
                p.getGenre(),
                p.getPublisher(),
                p.getLength(),
                p.getArtist(),
                c
                );




    digiProductList.updateEmployee(cd);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Album " + p.getAlbumName()
            + " Updated");

}





public JTextField[] getDigiProdDetailBx() {
    return digiProdDetailBx;
}


public void setDigiProdDetailBx(JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx) {
    this.digiProdDetailBx = digiProdDetailBx;
}


public JTextField[] getDigiProdDetailBx2() {
    return digiProdDetailBx2;
}


public void setDigiProdDetailBx2(JTextField[] digiProdDetailBx2) {
    this.digiProdDetailBx2 = digiProdDetailBx2;
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource().equals(update))
    {

        updateEmployee();
    }
    else if(e.getSource().equals(addSong))
    {
        addFields(2, true);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }
    else if(e.getSource().equals(addAlbum))
    {
        prodDialog.addSongs();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: what are DigiProduct, DigiProductList and ProdDialog ?

Comment: DigiProduct is a Jpanel, ProdDialog  is a JDialog, and DigiProductList  is my model for adding digital product to an ArrayList

Comment: Sorry DigiProduct is a object of type DigiProduct .

Comment: without their definitions, its difficult to understand the complete code, state your requirement (like adding textfield on the go) and I'll help you to create that

Comment: Ok I have database full of CD products, this UI I'm working on displays the songs from the product, I want it to also allow me to add new songs, if it's a new CD product there will be no songs already in the UI, so on the click of a button I want to add a new textfield and keep adding as many as I need, if this is an existing CD product there will already be textfields in UI populated with the details, I would like to be bale to add more textfields to the UI at this stage. I hope that explains my needs, and appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: So your problem is that when you add new textFields, they overlap the existing ones ? Also, what are you using the Repaint method for ?

Comment: If they were already there yes, but my main problem at the moment is that the text fields don't appear at the sizes I have set them, they are just lines as if I have not set preferred sizes for them.
The repaint method is to repaint the JPanel so the textFields are visible, I believe.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

> the text fields don't appear at the sizes I have set them

Suggest a size in the number of columns:

```
song1 = new JTextField(5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I abandoned adding them this way and instead added them on creation of the JDialog with a JoptionInputDialog for the amount of fields, not as pretty, but It will do for now.
the reason the JTextFields were not showing was because of the .repaint(), once I removed it they showed up fine.

Comment: *"once I removed it they showed up fine"*  You are seeing random behavior.  It might work on two PCs but fail on a third.  There are so many (other) problems with that code it is difficult to know where to begin.  But post an MCVE if you would like to fix them.  I've gone as far as I am willing with uncompilable code snippets.

Comment: I'm sure there is a lot wrong with my code, I am a student after all. I'd love to get it all absolutely perfect, but unfortunately I'm on a deadline and I don't have the time or knowledge to fix it all.
I appreciate your help and will take any advice on good coding ethics you give me.